# Compare two handwritten signatures in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to compare two handwritten signatures. The user adds 2 signatures (and the app saves it in Firebase) and later I want to check whether these two signatures are the same. I already made the saving in firebase and retrieving them into 2 imageviews. What I do not know is that how I can start comparing them. I would be satisfied if I could achieve that the application gives the difference between them. E.g. the difference between them is 2% so I can say that probably they are the same.

Comment: You're going to want to research computer vision and specific machine learning algorithms for signature recognition and verification. You're most probably best off outsourcing this to a 3rd party provider instead of having to deal with the complexities of the implementation yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly do this comparison over native android programming. You might need to avail a API based 3rd party tool to compare the image which might give you the % of similarity.

[best way to compare images for similarity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235701/best-way-to-compare-images-for-similarity-in-android)